# Not able to debug individual browser action js files in React Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension using react which has a background script and multiple browser action js files. This is my project structure

```
MyExtension
|__build
|__public
|    |__images
|    |__scripts
|    |__index.html
|    |__manifest.json
|
|__src
    | 
    |___browser action js files...
```

And this is my manifest.json

```
    {
      "name": "MyExtension",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "description": "MyExtension",
      "icons": {
        "16": "images/icon-16.png",
        "128": "images/icon-128.png"
      },
      "default_locale": "en",
      "background": {
        "scripts": [
          "scripts/background.js"
        ],
        "persistent": false
      },
      "permissions": [
        "background",
        "notifications",
        "tabs",
        "storage",
        "alarms",
        "webNavigation",
        "*://*/"
      ],
      "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
          "16": "images/icon-16.png",
          "19": "images/icon-19.png",
          "38": "images/icon-38.png",
          "128": "images/icon-128.png"
        },
        "default_title": "MyExtension",
        "default_popup": "index.html"
      },
      "web_accessible_resources": [
        "images/icon-48.png"
      ],
      "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'sha256- 
    5As4+3YpY62+l38PsxCEkjB1R4YtyktBtRScTJ3fyLU='; object-src 'self'"
```

}

I use the command `npm run build` for building the project where `build` is set to `react-scripts build`. Earlier, I used to debug the browser action files by inspecting the extension popup and setting breakpoints in js files under the `src` directory in the **Source** directory of the chrome developer tools window. I used to debug the background script by clicking on the `background page` link in the chrome://extensions page which is shown in the image below.

[image: Snapshot of chrome extension. I am able to debug the background script by clicking the "background page" link in the image below.]

But recently, I notice that the browser action source files are not present under the 'Sources' tab as shown in the image below.

[image: Source files are not present in Chrome Developer Tools]

I just get two chunk.js files which seem to be the bundled version of all my files in the src directory. They have a lot of auto-generated code and hence I am not able to set breakpoints in the files I want.

Is there any way for me to get the individual source files to appear in the **Sources** tab of the Developer Tools Window?

Comment: instead of building a production build, try `npm start` to just watch the files. Or make sure your webpack is configured to generate source maps.

Comment: @Vaibhav, I configured webpack to generate source maps, but still I am not getting it. `npm start` did show my files in a separate tab but I can't debug them unless they show up in the extension's "Inspect popup" window.

Comment: @wOxxOm By "browserAction" I mean the browserAction popup page which comes up when you right click on the extension icon and click "Inspect". Thank you for the link. But, I have been inspecting the right dev tools window, and so it wasn't of much help. I have updated my manifest.json in the question for your reference. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: how did you setup your React app, using CRA? If yes then eject, you will need to configure webpack manually. `npm start` should run webpack dev server so that you can get live updates as you edit your code. While `npm build` should the do the usual.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately, that didn't work either. I then tried running my extension on an older version of Chrome (Chrome 67) and I am able to see my js source files there. It is even visible in Opera too. The latest version of Chrome is hiding those files.